# Pylance: Import "requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry" could not be resolved from source

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have the following line in my project

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
```

Everything related to `requests` works with no problem, even the Retry

```
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

requests = Session()

retry = Retry(connect=8, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
requests.mount("http://", adapter)
requests.mount("https://", adapter)
```

But for some unknown reason, Pylance complains about `Retry` module cannot be found.

What can be this warning?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you change it to:

```
from urllib3.util import Retry
```

The Pylance not that smart. This is what in the `packages.py` file:

```
for package in ('urllib3', 'idna', 'chardet'):
    locals()[package] = __import__(package)
    # This traversal is apparently necessary such that the identities are
    # preserved (requests.packages.urllib3.* is urllib3.*)
    for mod in list(sys.modules):
        if mod == package or mod.startswith(package + '.'):
            sys.modules['requests.packages.' + mod] = sys.modules[mod]
```

Pylance could not speculate rightly with these codes.